# Complex Numbers Modulus in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, complex-numbers

Going by the following :-

```
>>>(9+2j)%(2+1j)
(1-2j)
>>>divmod(9+2j,2+1j)
((4+0j),(1-2j))
```

It shows that quotient is (4+0j) and remainder is (1-2j)  but how is it calculating ?

```
 >>>(9+2j)/(2+1j)
 (4-1j)
```

By this ,the answer comes out to be  (4-1j) and hence modulus will be 0.

How does modulus work with complex numbers in Python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

`divmod(x, y)` is (supposed to be) equivalent to `(x // y, x % y)`. For complex numbers, `x // y` gives the floor of the real part, rather than flooring the real and imaginary parts separately. `x % y` is then equal to `x - (x // y) * y`, so the following equality holds:

```
x = (x // y) * y + (x % y)
```

Note that in Python 3, `divmod` no longer accepts complex arguments. You can view the source code for [Python 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee924673d83a/Objects/complexobject.c#l620) and [Python 3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99190ebd4935/Objects/complexobject.c#l502) in the official Python source code repository.